# Profiling exercise with arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I want to create a code with 5 times 10 characters each can be thought of as a person's identity. Later, I will look at the identities of these people one by one and create features related to their codes. For example, if the code starts with the letter x, it will be female, if it starts with y and z, it will be male. I'm trying to do this with arrays, but when creating this population, where will I store 5 different codes and then how can I look IDs one by one.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max = 5;
    compAlien[] alien;
    alien = new compAlien[max];
    String[] letter = {"X", "Y", "Z"};
    String[] str = new String[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int w = rand.nextInt(letter.length);
        System.out.print(letter[w]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    int i = 1;
    while (max > 0) {
        System.out.println("ID:" + i + ", ");
        if (i == max) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

I also tried it like this but that didn't happen either.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max = 5;
    String[] IDs = new String[max];
    String[] letter = {"X", "Y", "Z"};
    for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
        int z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int w = rand.nextInt(letter.length);
            IDs[z] += letter[w];
        }
        z++;
    }
    System.out.println(IDs[0]);
    System.out.println(IDs[1]);
    System.out.println(IDs[2]);
    System.out.println(IDs[3]);
    System.out.println(IDs[4]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right way. But you mangled some of your vars.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max = 5;
    String[] IDs = new String[max];
    String[] letter = {"X", "Y", "Z"};
    for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
        IDs[j] = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int w = rand.nextInt(letter.length);
            IDs[j] += letter[w];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(IDs[0]);
    System.out.println(IDs[1]);
    System.out.println(IDs[2]);
    System.out.println(IDs[3]);
    System.out.println(IDs[4]);
}
```

You need to adress `IDs` with `j` not with a new `z`. `z` can even be eliminated.
Now you get the 5 desired strings. I have inserted `IDs[j] = ""` because you add the letters with `+=`. This means you would get strings like `nullXYZXYZXZYX`.
So we start with a clean string.
Happy coding.

Update to your follow-up question:
"Now I will determine the gender using these `IDs` in another method. How can I call this method there and what can I follow?"

There are some ways:

(a) You can use `IDs` as parameter for functioncalls:

```java
private static void doSomething(String[] IDs) {
    for (String ID : IDs) {
        System.out.println(ID);
    }
}
```

By this you can remove the `System.outs` and use only one call:

```java
doSomething(IDs);
```

(b) You can transfer the definition of `IDs` outside of main and make it a class-definition. This way you do not need to hand the variable `IDs` over to each and every function you may use. Each function can make usage of the data itself. But beware: usage of globals is a "nono" nowadays if not extremely needed. I would tend to (a).

Comment: Now I will determine the gender using these IDs in another method. How can I call this method there and what can I follow?

Comment: Added the answer to my original post. Hope that helps.